# How do I get my own TimeZone in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

looking for a way to get my own time zone that I can pass to config.time_zone in application.rb order to set it in Rails.   Background:  I'm allowing the user to specify their timezone in a yaml config, but if it's not set, I want to explicitly use the box's timezone.  I *have* to have a value set because I'm using it as reference to convert timezones for display -- each user logging into the Rails app can set their personal timezone and I will do the conversion for them.

However, there seems to be no good API for doing this in Ruby or Rails.  Time.now.zone returns the 3-letter code (EDT or CDT, for example), but you can't pass this because it's not specific enough -- the TZInfo class will only accept the "long" descriptions.

Here's what I'm doing now, which seems pretty hacky:

```
time_zone = CONFIG[:time_zone] # set your local time zone here. use rake time:zones:local to choose a value, or use UTC.

unless time_zone
  # try to detect one

  if File.exists?('/etc/localtime')
    path = File.readlink('/etc/localtime')
    items = path.split("zoneinfo/")
    if items.length == 2
      time_zone = items[1]
    end
  end

  unless time_zone
    puts "*** Warning:  no time zone is set in config/config.yaml and could not detect system time. Using UTC as the default time; behavior may be unexpected."
    time_zone = "UTC"
  end
end

config.time_zone = time_zone
```

Any better ideas guys?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following:

```
off_set = Time.now.gmt_offset
p ActiveSupport::TimeZone[off_set].name # "Atlantic Time (Canada)"
```

or

```
p ActiveSupport::TimeZone[off_set].tzinfo.name # "America/Halifax"
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I wonder what happens if when there are multiple timezones with the same GMT offset?

Comment: oh, i just looked up, it returns the first one:  "If it is a numeric value it is either the hour offset, or the second offset, of the timezone to find. (The first one with that offset will be returned.)" http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-5B-5D - so I guess this wouldn't be reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Any reason why this wouldn't work?:

`Time.now.zone`

Edit:

Before getting the zone, you can do `Time.now.gmt_offset` to get your GMT offset in seconds.  After that, you can do `Time.now.zone` to get your zone code.

Comment: It doesn't.  It returns a 3 letter code like CDT, which, for example, can mean Central Daylight Time (USA) OR Central Daylight Time (Australia).  So you can't pass it into config.time_zone or use it as a basis for converting timezones using TZInfo.

Comment: It may, is there an API that I can pass Time.now.gmt_offset + Time.now.zone in order to get a TimeZone name I can pass to config.time_zone or TZInfo::Timezone.get?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the time zone offset in hours, as some databases do (like Postgres), you can use this method:

```ruby
2.3.1 :063 > Time.zone.formatted_offset
"-07:00"
```

or this approach if you need the offset in seconds:

```ruby
2.3.1 :059 > Time.zone.utc_offset
-25200
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the 3-letter codes are not precise enough, have the user specify the full name from the [IANA time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=IANA_time_zone_database&redirect=no).

Then you can use `Time.zone = 'America/Halifax'` (for example).
`Time.zone.name` returns back the IANA name, and `Time.zone.now` returns the current time in the specified timezone.

To find the timezone in this format programically, you may be able to use `/etc/timezone` if it's available. Other systems have other methods (if there is even one available).